# Calling import.io dataset created with "Chain API" via REST

Tags: rest, import.io

I created a dataset using 2 extractors: a **"many rows"** extractor which is then called by a **"just one row"** extractor via the **"URLs from another API / Chain APIs"** option. This has given me the data that I need and I have saved it as a dataset. Although the dataset is working I'm lost as to how to use the REST API to retrieve it?

I'm aware that there used to be an "integrate" button on the dataset page which would outline how to use an external client library to get the data but in it's absence now I don't know which of the APIs to use and how to use them?

I've attempted at using the **"Query Methods"** **GET** call **"/store/connector/{id}/_query"** but it requires an **"id"** which I don't know where to find from? I attempted to use the **"_connectorVersionGuid"** value when I saved the dataset as JSON but that didn't work.

Any help and advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 2):

AJ,

Francesco here, from import.io. 
First of all, thanks for formulating the question so clearly.

I have bad news and good news.

The bad news is at the moment Bulk and Chain are only available as client side feature, so it's not really possible to call a chain with a single REST call.

The good news is that we are actually working on it :)
Bulk as an API is actually in beta testing, and I hope to have a Chain as an API as well.

A workaround I sometimes use myself is to use an external integration as a service platform, like Node-RED (http://nodered.org/) or built.io (https://www.built.io/)

Comment: Thank you for the speedy answer Francesco. It's good to hear that the APIs are being worked on but indeed in the meantime I'll use the external integration services that you suggested. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry fast typing
I meant: you're very welcome AJ, by the way Scheduled and Bulk APIs are coming out in Beta now. Join the facebook group if you're interested in beta testing them! :)

Comment: Maybe you should mention this a bit more clearly in your documentation, I love your service and it works amazingly but I almost spend an hour searching for this to finally end up here. Thanks for your product though, love it!

Comment: It's good feedback - I forwarded it to the support folks so they can update the doc page. Thanks also for the kind words, always appreciated! :)